# If $A\cap B= \emptyset \Rightarrow \bar{A}\cap\dot{B} = \emptyset$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

$A\cap B= \emptyset \Rightarrow \bar{A}\cap\overset{\,\circ}{B} = \emptyset$

This should be a really simple question but I cannot seem to work it out. I suppose there is an element $x \in \bar{A}\cap\overset{\,\circ}{B}$ then it must also be $x \in \bar{A}$ and $x\in B$. So I now only have to show that it must be in $A$ also. I suppose it is not, then it must be in $\partial A$. But I cannot seem to arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: If you take $A$ to be a generic point of a variety, then the statement is wrong. There must be more conditions, such as being Hausdorff I guess.

Comment: Both A,B are subset of X thats the only condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A \cap B = \emptyset$ implies $$A \subseteq B^\complement$$ (complement in the space $X$)

so $$\operatorname{int}(A) \subseteq \operatorname{int}(B^\complement)$$ follows by taking interior on both sides, which preserves inclusion.

By a standard duality identity we have $$\operatorname{int}(B^\complement)=(\overline{B})^\complement$$

so $$\operatorname{int}(A) \subseteq (\overline{B})^\complement$$

or $$\operatorname{int}(A) \cap \overline{B}= \emptyset$$

as required.

Answer (score 2):

By definition of interior there must be an open set $U$ such that $x\in U\subseteq B$. Since $x\in\overline{A}$ we have $A\cap U\ne\emptyset$, i.e there is some element $y\in A\cap U$. But then $y\in A\cap B$ (since $U\subseteq B$), a contradiction.

Comment: How did you get $A\cap U$ to be non-empty?

Comment: @User By the definition $\overline A$: we have $x\in\overline A$ if and only if every open $U$ with $x\in U$ contains a point of $A$.